# UITableView didSelectRow returns wrong row index value

Tags: swift, uitableview

When I select a row it returns a row index value bigger or smaller but never the correct value. As on the picture I selected 14 returned 16.

[image: selected 14 returned 16]

Here is the code I use:

```
  @IBOutlet var cheatTable: UITableView!

  let cheetSheet = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    cheatTable.delegate = self
    cheatTable.dataSource = self
  }

  func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 30
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseID")!
    let text:String = "\(indexPath.row)"
    cell.textLabel?.text = text
    return cell
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) else {
      return
    }
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Hint", message: "You have selected row \(indexPath.row).", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let alertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(alertAction)
    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
```

What could I do to get the correct row index?
Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

check your delegate name is not **`didDeselectRowAt`** it is **`didSelectRowAt`**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)


    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Hint", message: "You have selected row \(indexPath.row).", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let alertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(alertAction)
    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

as per your code follow I created the [sample project](https://www.sendspace.com/file/lu9b4h)